# Linux Terminal not accepting entered text

Tags: terminal, debian-based

I am using Raspbian, similar to Debian, and I am trying to login as superuser. I have ran both $su and $su - and both have required a password, but as I go to type in a password, none of the characters I type are displayed, and after i have typed in the whole password, it still does not think I have typed in anything. Copy and paste does not work, and I'm not sure quite what to do. I am a beginner when it comes to linux, so I might have missed an obvious step. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The password not displaying is a security measure and to be expected. You did remember to press the Enter key after typing the password, didn't you? If so, what message did you get?

Comment: I did hit enter, and I was greeted by "Authentication failure". Thanks though for letting me know that it was not supposed to render the text. Is the super user password different than the normal password to sign onto the computer? I am using the only account on the computer, and I'm not sure what else the password would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Raspbian FAQ includes instructions for [making a proper root account](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianFAQ#How_do_I_make_a_proper_root_account.3F), which suggests that it doesn't come with one set up by default.

Pay particular attention to the first line:

> Don't do this unless you're certain that you want and need a true root account. sudo will take care of root tasks for you nicely in almost all cases.

In other words, you'll probably find that you can skip doing the `su` that's failing, and instead just prefix the commands that need to run as the super-user with `sudo`.

For example, if you were supposed to do `mkdir x/y/z` then you'd do `sudo mkdir x/y/z` instead. You'll still be asked for a password, but it will be **yours** not a password for the root account.

If there are lots of commands you need to run as super user, you might find you can do `sudo bash` to enter a new shell with root privileges, then run the commands without needing the sudo prefix, then `exit` to get back to your normal shell.